# How can I disable lightdm auto-login from the command-line when isn't possible to get a GUI session?

Tags: command-line, login, lightdm

Suppose auto-login to a session is active in Ubuntu. So there will not be an opportunity to select a session (e.g gnome, unity, kde, etc). But if the environment is corrupted there is no way to escape except command line.

Is there a way to disable auto-login without relying on GUI session

Comment: I do not know what implies that I use lightdm so that it is edited to lightdm. I use kdm.

Comment: You did not specify that you use KDM, so that usually means you use the default, lightdm. You should edit the question to add that essential information and then we can get the answers updated.

Answer (score 5):

To stop lightdm from automatically logging in user `bob`, edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and change the line

```
autologin-user=bob
```

to

```
autologin-user=
```

(the `=` will be the line's last character)

Comment: I don't know how to edit using command line.

Comment: What editors do you know? There may be a command-line equivalent.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus just run `nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` that's a very simple to use text editor.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed` to do it automatically:

```
sudo sed -i.backup -e 's/autologin-user=\(.*\)/autologin-user=/ /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

This will change the first occurrence of `autologin-user=someUser` with `autologin-user=` (replace `someUser` with whatever user was set to auto login). It will also create a backup of the original file named `lightdm.conf.backup`.

Or you could simply delete the line completely:

```
sudo sed -i.backup '/autologin-user=/d' /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

I tested both methods on a fresh 12.04.5 VM and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> and

1. Login
2. `sudo service "name of login manager" stop`

Usually this service is either gdm or lightdm.

Comment: this will stop gdm, etc. Will it disable auto-login when compter is restarted?

Comment: No you need to stop gdm then reconfigure it then restart, see [Disable Autologin](http://askubuntu.com/questions/266871/ubuntu-automatically-logs-in-as-gdm-how-do-i-stop-this)

Comment: Why was this voted down?? just curious

Comment: Your answer is wrong, it doesn't answer the question. You are just stopping the display manager, not disabling auto-login.

Comment: But look at the comment above yours.  I suppose I could include this...

Comment: Comments aren't answers ;)

Comment: Well this helped me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using lightdm for logging, but have no GUI, you may run the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

You will see a row `autologin-user=username`, you may comment it with `#` or simply delete the `username` statement.

Afterwards, in command line run `sudo service lightdm restart` or simply restart your PC.

Comment: gksudo needs the GUI (GTK to be more precise), which OP shouldn't be able to use.

Comment: As does `gedit` itself.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Fixed answer