# Get password login for opensuse 13.2?

Tags: kde, opensuse, login

Hello I am using OpenSuse 13.2 **KDE** 
How to get login protected ie. **Password**
when i switch on my system i go directly on on (without password vitrifaction )

Comment: What display manager does OpenSuse use? For LightDM, you try: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159083/how-can-i-disable-lightdm-auto-login-from-the-command-line-when-isnt-possible-t

Comment: Not Lightdm , Mdm or Gdm..for opensuse

Comment: See if you have entries mentioned in https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM#Automatic_login in `/etc/gdm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind If found it myself :-

open system setting **>>** Yast **>>** security and users **>>** user and group management .

On right bottom click on **Expert option**

then select login setting & un-select **auto-login**

**Via terminal :-**

open under any **editor**

> sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/displaymanager
>
> DISPLAYMANAGER_AUTOLOGIN="**your_username**"

**TO**

```
    > DISPLAYMANAGER_AUTOLOGIN=""
```

Comment: You can also edit `/etc/sysconfig/displaymanager` and change `DISPLAYMANAGER_AUTOLOGIN="ashutoshkale"` to `DISPLAYMANAGER_AUTOLOGIN=""`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick can i add this in answer?

Comment: Sure, go ahead and add it. If you can, include in your answer the two documentation lines that precede it, `# Define the user whom should get logged in without request. If string` and `# is empty, display standard login dialog.`